# Is it possible to schedule a job from the build parameters instead of setting up a trigger?

Tags: triggers, teamcity

I would like to give the option when the run|... job option is clicked and in the build parameters to set a time to run this job. Setting this as a trigger is not a option, 1) each day may be different, but it's at night so setting it would be nice. 2) the user does not have permissions to config this job. So i'd like to add a window for the user to be able to choose from the build parameters tab, something like 12:00am, 1:00am, etc... Is this possible? I can't link a dependency to another job in this scenario either.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible -- the `Run...` button queues the build for the next available agent, and agents can't be restricted to only run during certain periods of time.  Is a scheduled build trigger insufficient for your needs?  If so, you can always [request this feature](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/teamcity) from JetBrains.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, a scheduled build trigger won't work for this particular job. The time it needs to run each night is determined each day, and the person who would determine this does not have access to edit the job configuration.

Comment: The JetBrains folks are pretty responsive to new feature requests. It'd definitely be worth a shot to request a `Run at...` option.

Answer (score 1):

The related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-6439, please vote for it.
As current workaround you can trigger a build with needed parameters using [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild) and then use the logic in a cron job or from another scheduled-triggered TeamCity build.